# ResourceManager does not start

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, apache-zookeeper

I installed Hadoop (HDP 2.5.3) on 4 VMs with Ambari (1 Ambari Server and 3 Ambari Clients; with the DNS entries *server*, *node0*, *node1*, *node2*) with HDFS, YARN, MapReduce and Zookeeper.

However, YARN doesn't want to start. When starting the Resource Manager on node1 I get the following error:

```
resource_management.core.exceptions.ExecutionFailed: Execution of 'curl -sS -L -w '%{http_code}' -X GET 'http://node0:50070/webhdfs/v1/ats/done/?op=GETFILESTATUS&user.name=hdfs' 1>/tmp/tmpgsiRLj 2>/tmp/tmpMENUFa' returned 7. curl: (7) Failed to connect to node0 port 50070: connection refused 000
```

App Timeline Server and History Server on node1 don't want to start either. Zookeeper, NameNode, DataNode and Nodemanager on Node0 is up. The nodes can reach each other (tried with ping) so that shouldn't be the problem.

Hopefully one can help me. I'm really new to this topic and not really familiar with the system.

Comment: Are you able to ping each other using hostname from all machines?

Comment: yes, I can `ping server/node0/node1/node2` every node/server from every node/server

Answer (score 0):

You should check the host file (`/etc/hosts`), see the host name and FNDN, check if there any duplicates name, IP address.

Could you also confirm the firewall activity by steps:

```
sudo ufw status
```

And also [check the port in iptables](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Communication-issues-50070-connection-refused-while/td-p/215142) (or allow port in firewall: udp, tcp).